# In Kotlin, is there a more native way to compare by integer, then string?

Tags: kotlin

I'm sorting a list of `Pair<Int, String>` with this:

```
list.sortedWith(Comparator.comparingInt<Pair<String, Int>> { it.second }
    .thenComparing { it -> it.first })
```

It seems a bit odd to have to specify `{ it ->` so is there something more Kotlin-ish I should be using?

---

Edit: Sorry, I got lost while asking the question: while I did want to know the answers below, what I suppose I was really curious about was why I can't leave out the `it ->`:

This compiles:

```
var c = Comparator
    .comparingInt<Pair<String, Int>> { it.second }
    .thenComparing { it -> it.first }
```

This complains with 'unresolved reference `it`':

```
 var c = Comparator
     .comparingInt<Pair<String, Int>> { it.second }
     .thenComparing { it.first }
```

Comment: You can always omit `it ->` in a lambda when the type can be inferred, because `it` is an implicit parameter for single-parameter lambdas: `{ it.first }`

Comment: Yeah, I tried removing the it -> and IntelliJ didn't like that. I suppose that was my real question - why omitting 'it ->' doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what you're looking for:

```
sortedWith(compareBy({ it.first }, {it.second})
```

Comment: It certainly is, but I changed my question a bit: I forgot that what was really bugging me was why I needed 'it ->' in the second clause of the comparator, and what I should have been doing not to need it - whether there's a way to have Comparator.xxxx { it.first }.yyyy { it.second }.